# LINQ - Is Contains much faster than Equals(==)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that returns a large amount of data based on the ID I provide.

```
results = (from x in database
          where x.ID == MY_SELECTED_ID
          select x).ToList();
```

It took around 40 seconds to execute that query.

Then I created another query:

```
results = (from x in database
           where 
           (MyIDList.Contains(SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.ID).Trim())
           select x).ToList();
```

It took around 10-15 seconds to execute that query.

So, is Contains faster when it has to do with large amount of data?

Thanks

Comment: Measure that again, several times and in different orders. This looks like the result of caching.  Benchmarking is _not_ easy. You have to know all factors involved.

Comment: You can see what query is generated. There is a way to log them in the debug window. Compare them..

Comment: Welcome to SO! Take the queries that are generated and run them on the DBMS after clearing the cache.

Comment: In linq to sql, c#'s `==` equals to `=` in sql and c#'s `Contains()` method translates into sql's `IN`.

Comment: at least for entity framework for .net core I have experienced the opposite where .Contains was evaluated in code and thus much slower. My advice is to open a profiler if it is Sql Server and see what is actually generated.

Comment: @MaciejLos No, for this example `Contains` will generate sql's `IN`: `WHERE ID IN(MyIDList[0], MyIDList[1], .. MyIDList[N])`

Comment: How much data does your other query return? Since the two queries will produce different answers, they aren't really comparable. What are you trying to figure out?